# Tsql: LOWERCASE using with IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question concerning the lower function.

```
,case when lower(replace(producttitle, ‘ ‘, ‘‘)) in (‘microphone‘) then ‘YES‘ else ‘NO‘ end
```

The statement above does select only YES, when column value = value in the IN function.

I want to get a YES when the value such as it is written in the IN function. When the column value is ‘Microphone‘, i want to get it lowercase —> microphone and because the IN containts ‘microphone‘, I should get a YES, right?

When the column value is Microphone (upper B), why do I not get it lower? Such as in the IN function.

Example: column value: ‘Microphone‘
I want to get a YES by making the column value lower and because the IN function contains the value (‘microphone‘)

Thank you

Comment: Are you selecting `LOWER(producttitle)` or just `producttitle`?

Comment: With lowercase, lower(prducttitle)

Comment: In that case it should be lowercase. Is this part of a sub-query or do you have the wrong field? Could you please copy your full `SELECT` as the code supplied doesn't show what is needed for your question?

Comment: I edited my question above. This is the whole select. I just have the same case when (multiple case when statements) for multiple columns, same logic.

Comment: You're still only showing the one column though. Maybe I've misunderstood your question. Are you expecting results along the line of "microphone, Yes" but you're getting "Microphone, Yes"?

Comment: I expect getting a YES as the case statements shows. But I get a NO because the case statements checks only, if columnvalue = value in the IN function. But It should do also the lowercase, right?

Comment: `SELECT case when lower(replace('Microphone', ' ', '')) in ('microphone') then 'YES' else 'NO' end` returns "YES". If you run that code, do you also get "YES"?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Here's a [Rextester demo.](https://rextester.com/HJFEA76023)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the collation to make it case `sensitive`, by default it is case `insensitive` :

```
CASE WHEN REPLACE(producttitle, ' ', '') = 'microphone' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
     THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
END
```